# Does IFormFile read the file from the client automatically in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, iformfile

I have IFormFile in my Razor model and I'm submitting it to the server. When I get there will the file be read from the client or do I need to do it manually.

The idea is that I want to use CopyToAsync but I'm afraid that I'm going to allocate memory for the file twice if it is already in memory.

Comment: Have you tried it out?

Comment: I have no way to test that. That is why I'm asking. :)

Comment: Yes you have. If you set a breakboint at your controller after you have submitted it and it is not null, it is in memory.

Comment: The whole thing? Not only the metadata(lenght, name, etc..)? So if I do a copy I will allocate memory twice. That is not good.

Comment: Yes, that is the point of submitting something to the server. If you need it else where, you can always offload it onto a fileshare, database or SessionServer and re-load it again anytime you need it.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out I didn't know how http works in this situation. I thought that it does not go all the way and I have to read it from a stream manually.